# html agility pack vs antixss

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, xss, antixsslibrary

It seems to me just using the html agility pack would work to prevent xss (parse then get innertext). Would it be repetitive to use antixss after using hap?

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apples and oranges.

The HTML Agility Pack is a tool to parse HTML and work with the resulting parsed document.

the AntiXSSLibrary is a tool to use on your HTML and website to prevent XSS.

Comparing the two does not make much sense to me.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if HTML Agility Pack is suitable for preventing XSS. In other words does it do what AntiXSSLibrary does and more, or would it be practical to use them side by side?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan - yes, I thought that explaining that the two **do different things** makes it clear that no, it isn't suitable by itself.